# QDockWidget not showing content at first sight

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt5

I'm loading the QDockWidget and it does load fine and has the content but it seems that doesn't have a fixed size that avoids it's content to be hidden once loaded.

this is how it looks when is loaded:

[image]

and this is how it looks when manually drag it open (and how should look when loaded):

[image]

code:

```
    self.mdo = QMdiArea()
    self.buttons = QDockWidget('buttons', self.mdo)
    self.buttonsreen = QWidget()
    self.buttonsreen.resize(400,300)
    self.buttonsreen.setWindowTitle('direccion')

    self.btnfront = QPushButton('adelante', self.buttonsreen)
    self.btnfront.setToolTip('avanza una foto')
    self.btnfront.resize(self.btnfront.sizeHint())
    self.btnfront.move(200, 0)
    self.btnfront.clicked.connect(frontbutton)

    self.btnback = QPushButton('atras', self.buttonsreen)
    self.btnback.setToolTip('retrocede una foto')
    self.btnback.resize(self.btnback.sizeHint())
    self.btnback.move(0,0)
    self.btnback.clicked.connect(backbutton) 
    self.buttons.setWidget(self.buttonsreen)
    self.iface.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.buttons)
```

How is it forced to open with that specific size and how do I avoid other widgets to hide the buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem you just need to add this line to the code:

```
self.buttonsreen.setMinimumSize(QSize(400,30))
```

To set a size rule to the Widget going inside the QDockWidget, in this case `self.buttonscreen` meaning that this widget can't be resized to less than width=400 and height=30

So in the end it would look like:

```
self.mdo = QMdiArea()
self.buttons = QDockWidget('Direccion', self.mdo)
self.buttonsreen = QWidget()

self.btnfront = QPushButton('adelante', self.buttonsreen)
self.btnfront.setToolTip('avanza una foto')
self.btnfront.resize(self.btnfront.sizeHint())
self.btnfront.move(200, 0)
self.btnfront.clicked.connect(frontbutton)

self.btnback = QPushButton('atras', self.buttonsreen)
self.btnback.setToolTip('retrocede una foto')
self.btnback.resize(self.btnback.sizeHint())
self.btnback.move(0,0)
self.btnback.clicked.connect(backbutton) 

self.buttons.setWidget(self.buttonsreen)
self.buttonsreen.setMinimumSize(QSize(400,30))

self.iface.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.buttons)
```